# Chinese Remainder Theorem with non coprime modul0 to the power

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

> Determine the remainder of $2^{666}\pmod {2016}$ with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I started with 2016 = $2^{5}$.$3^{2}$.$7$

I made:
$$x \equiv 2^{666} \pmod{2^{5}}$$
$$x \equiv 2^{666} \pmod9$$
$$x \equiv 2^{666} \pmod7$$

Because 2 and 9 are coprime and 2 and 7, I used Euler's totient function to simplify it.

- $\phi (9)$ = 6 and $\phi (7)$ = 6.
- 666 = 111.6 + 0

So:

$$x \equiv 2^{666} \pmod{2^{5}}$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod9$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod7$$

But because 2 and $2^{5}$ are not coprime how could I simplify it and find the remainder with the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{5}}$

Comment: @ZackNi Could you explain?

Comment: $x \equiv 2^{666} \equiv 2^5 \times 2^{661} \equiv 0 \times 2^{661} \equiv 0  \pmod{2^{5}}$

Comment: Well, that's embarassing, thanks!

Comment: It boils down to $\  x = 32y \equiv 1\equiv 64\pmod{63}\ $ so $\ y \equiv\,\ldots\ \ $